# printing contents when connected to database using perl

Tags: mysql, perl

Below, is the code to connect mysql database and retrieving results using perl.

In the below example, samples table has 10 columns. I just want the second and third columns of record 99 into variables.

Can some one help me in this?

```
use strict;
 use warnings;
 use DBI;

my $dbh = DBI->connect('dbi:mysql:perltest','root','password') or die "Connection Error: $DBI::errstr\n";
my $sql = "select * from samples where record='99'";
my $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute or die "SQL Error: $DBI::errstr\n";
while (my @row = $sth->fetchrow_array) {
 print "@row\n";
 }
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code will get you the second and third columns of the row into variables:

```
while (my @row = $sth->fetchrow_array) {
     $var1 = @row[1];
     $var2 = @row[2];
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Its working. I also tried this "print join("<br>",@row);" to display all contents sepatrated by new line in the array "@row". I wrote "<br>" in the print statement, because I am working perl cgi.

Comment: Pardon me. I think I am reading it wrong. Shouldn't that be `$row[1]` and `$row[2]` instead of `@row[1]` and `@row[2]`.

Comment: @Dheeraj: Yes, it absolutely should, since `@row[1]` and `@row[2]` are one element array slices. Slices are redundant here, unless you replace those two rows with `($var1, $var2) = @row[1,2];`. As it stands now, this would produce the warning `Scalar value @row[1] better written as $row[1]` and similar for the other assignment with `use warnings;` Shame on him for not using warnings.